# NodeJS + MySQL, connection error after idle time

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

I'm new to NodeJS, and I'm starting to try to run small projects. I'm having a problem connecting to mysql, I've tried a few examples, they all work fine except when I leave the server running and idle for around a day. When the page is reloaded, it generates a connection problem, where it gives an error when executing the sql query because the connection with the database is closed.
Ideas on how to resolve?
I'll post below the code I'm using for this.

db.js

```
async function connect(){
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
    if(global.connection && global.connection.state !== 'disconnected')
        return global.connection;

    const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
        host: '**', 
        user: '**', 
        password: '**', 
        database: '**' 
    });
    console.log("Conn MySQL!");
    global.connection = connection;
    return connection;
}


async function sqlquery(q){
    const conn = await connect();
    const [rows] = await conn.query(q);
    return rows;
}

module.exports = {sqlquery}
```

Im using socket.io
index.js

```
io.on('connection', (client) => {
            if (client.request.headers.referer.includes("tab")){
                (async () => {
                    const sql = require("./db");
                io.sockets.emit('/content', await sql.sqlquery('select query here'));
                })();
            }            
        });
```

nodemon error report

```
path>nodemon index.js
[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Timeline Server!
26/06/2023, 08:25:31
Conn MySQL!


26/06/2023, 13:00:53
27/06/2023, 09:37:23
path\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:93
    const localErr = new Error();
                     ^

Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state
    at PromiseConnection.query (\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:93:22)
    at Object.sqlquery (\db.js:27:31)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async \index.js:60:43 {
  code: undefined,
  errno: undefined,
  sql: undefined,
  sqlState: undefined,
  sqlMessage: undefined
}

Node.js v18.16.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

See that yesterday the 26/06th at 13:00 it worked perfectly, I left the project running but I didn't open the web page anymore, today the 27th at 9:37 am I reloaded the page and it reported the error saying that the connection was closed. However, in the db.js file it apparently only executes the query when there is a connection, but that's not what happens. Any idea how to resolve? (I saw examples using connection pooling, but I didn't get to test it).